# python subscriber to a uvc_camera non-compressed Image?

Tags: ros, python, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've previously used this tutorial to get a CompressImage from a web camera: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingImagePublisherSubscriber

Now I'm using a webcamera through uvc_camera, and it isn't publishing a compressed image.  If I substitute Image for CompressedImage in the python code the cv_image comes out as None.

```
  ...
     # subscribed Topic
     self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/image_raw",
         Image, self.callback,  queue_size = 1)
  ....
  def callback(self, ros_data):
  ...

      #### direct conversion to CV2 ####
      np_arr = np.fromstring(ros_data.data, np.uint8)
      image_np = cv2.imdecode(np_arr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

np_arr at this point is a (width*height*3, ) array, but image_np comes out `None`.

The camera otherwise works fine in rqt_image_view.  Is there any way to get uvc_camera to compress, another node to add that will compress for me, or get the np/cv2 commands to process the non-compressed data properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159931/python-subscriber-to-a-uvc_camera-non-compressed-image?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing the compressed image ros packages solved my problems, though I'm still curious about subscribing to an uncompressed image.

This caused the uvc_camera to publish a compressed image instead of just a raw uncompressed:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-compressed-image-transport
```

image_transport republish may also work but I have not tried it.  http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#republish

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0